# Magento 2 : How to export my custom grid data in product edit page admin?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, grid, export

**When I click Export Button**

[image]

> Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="grid" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\RelatedOrderGrid</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\RelatedOrderGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager as ModuleManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class RelatedOrderGrid extends AbstractModifier
{
const GROUP_REVIEW = 'order';
const GROUP_CONTENT = 'content';
const DATA_SCOPE_REVIEW = 'grouped';
const SORT_ORDER = 20;
const LINK_TYPE = 'associated';

protected $locator;

protected $urlBuilder;

private $moduleManager;

public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}

public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() || !$this->getModuleManager()->isOutputEnabled('Magento_Review')) {
        return $meta;
    }

    $meta[static::GROUP_REVIEW] = [
        'children' => [
            'order_listing' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'autoRender' => true,
                            'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                            'dataScope' => 'order_listing',
                            'externalProvider' => 'order_listing.order_listing_data_source',
                            'selectionsProvider' => 'order_listing.order_listing.product_columns.ids',
                            'ns' => 'order_listing',
                            'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                            'realTimeLink' => false,
                            'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                            'externalFilterMode' => true,
                            'imports' => [
                                'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id'
                            ],
                            'exports' => [
                                'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Order History'),
                    'collapsible' => true,
                    'opened' => false,
                    'componentType' => Form\Fieldset::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' =>
                        $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                            $meta,
                            static::GROUP_CONTENT,
                            static::SORT_ORDER
                        ),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $meta;
}

public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();

    $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_product_id'] = $productId;

    return $data;
}

private function getModuleManager()
{
    if ($this->moduleManager === null) {
        $this->moduleManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ModuleManager::class);
    }
    return $this->moduleManager;
}
}
```

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\order_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">order_listing.order_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <spinner>order_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>order_listing.order_listing_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="order_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>Meetanshi_OrderHistory::orders_all</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\RelatedOrderData" name="order_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>entity_id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>review_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters_modifier" xsi:type="array"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <statefull>

            </statefull>
        </settings>
        <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                <caption translate="true">Store Views</caption>
                <label translate="true">Purchased From</label>
                <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="order_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="increment_id" sortOrder="1">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
            <label translate="true">Order Id</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="status" sortOrder="2" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="store_id" sortOrder="3" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Store View</label>
            <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" sortOrder="4" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
        <settings>
            <filter>dateRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_firstname" sortOrder="5">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Customer FirstName</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_lastname" sortOrder="6">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Customer LastName</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_email" sortOrder="7">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Customer Email</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="original_price" sortOrder="8" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\GrandTotal">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Original Price</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="subtotal" sortOrder="9" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\GrandTotal">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Order Price</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="grand_total" sortOrder="10" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\GrandTotal">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Order Total</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ReviewActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">sales/order/view</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <indexField>order_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
</listing>
```

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\RelatedOrderData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;

class RelatedOrderData extends AbstractDataProvider
{

protected $collectionFactory;

protected $request;

public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    RequestInterface $request,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getData()
{
    $productid = $this->request->getParam('current_product_id', 0);


    $this->collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            'sales_order_item',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id'
        )->where('sales_order_item.product_id = '.$productid);

    $arrItems = [
        'totalRecords' => $this->collection->getSize(),
        'items' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        $arrItems['items'][] = $item->toArray([]);
    }

    return $arrItems;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you fixed this ?